# IE unable to load assets

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I'm having a wierd issue with IE versions 8 and 9. In two pages within my application, instead of loading any external assets (CSS, JS, Images etc.) all I get is a plain text page.

Loading JS scripts is *attempted*, but their content is replaced with the HTML source of the page (causing JS syntax errors).

CSS and images do not appear in the resource tree at all.

All content is there (including any inline styles), and all other pages are working fine, plus the two failing pages are fine in all other browsers (including IE10).

I've been pulling my hair out over this for a while, and can't recreate the issue anywhere outside this particular application. Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: Obviously hard to diagnose wthout seeing your code. Please post the code of your HTML page here. Do you have a valid doctype specified?

Comment: Maybe there is a syntax error in these pages that mess with the rendering? Any chance you can post the source?

Comment: or a link to the site would also do the trick

Comment: Get IEHTTPHeaders from http://www.blunck.info/iehttpheaders.html‎ installed on your IE8 machine, and look use it to look at the response headers for that particular page.

Comment: Well, this is where it gets *really* strange. Unfortunately, the pages in question are within a secure application which I cannot provide a login for.

However, if I log into the application and save the generated source from the failing page as a static HTML file, I can then load this file perfectly fine in IE8. Link: http://dev.solcost.co.uk/james-test3.html

The Source is *identical* to that which is displayed when logging into the application (tested in file compare app), and all resources are being loaded from the same locations.

Apologies if that doesn't help much

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski I've run the page with IEHTTPHeaders installed, don't 100% understand the output though. I think everything looks OK, here it is: http://dev.solcost.co.uk/IE_HTTP_Responses.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your response headers, all the requests for CSS and JS files are returning a Content-Type of `text/html` and roughly the same Content-Length.

This indicates that none of the resources are loading, responses of that nature indicate that the server is responding with something else, e.g. a custom 404 page / access denied / system error.

You have a `<base>` element at the top of your document, but the HREF is `/`, I *think* IE8 requires an absolute href (e.g. starting with `http://`).

Since your base href is `/` and your first CSS file is `public/css/melody.css` but your HTTP request is `GET /casesetup_update/edit/public/css/melody.css` so it's clearly being ignored.

This is the weirdest base href value I think I've ever seen, just use `/` at the start of your URLs (and no base href).

Comment: THAT'S IT! Putting in an absolute href has resolved it. You are a star! Been pulling my hair out over this for weeks.

Comment: FYI, the reason for using / as a base href is that the application sits in subfolders when run locally, so there the href would be /dev/, /test/ etc.

Comment: @JamesDinsdale oh I see, we use subdomains for that.

Comment: we do as well on the server, but on our local machines it runs in a folder within the Apache document root, so we can easily make copies/branches of the code without affecting the SVN working copies